# How can I pull the object from the json using a key?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I am working with Typescript. I want to iterate the below json file and pull the individual objects based on the search string.

```
{
  "menus": {
    "indian": [
        {
            "id": "000123",
            "name": "Dish 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "000124",
            "name": "Dish 2"
        },
        {
            "id": "000125,
            "name": "Dish 3"
        }
    ],
    "chinese": [
        {
            "id": "000126",
            "name": "Dish 4"
        },
        {
            "id": "000127",
            "name": "Dish 5"
        },
        {
            "id": "000128",
            "name": "Dish 6"
        }
    ],
    "tandoori": [
        {
            "id": "000129",
            "name": "Dish 7"
        },
        {
            "id": "000130",
            "name": "Dish 8"
        },
        {
            "id": "000131",
            "name": "Dish 9"
        }
    ]
   }
 }
```

I will map the response json with my model class

```
export interface Menu {
    indian: Item[];
    chinese: Item[];
    tabdoori: Item[];
}       

export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

const response: Menu = this.myApiService.getAllMenus();
```

For eg my input is "**indian**" then i need to pull the object from the json

```
"indian": [
            {
                "id": "000123",
                "name": "Dish 1"
            },
            {
                "id": "000124",
                "name": "Dish 2"
            },
            {
                "id": "000125,
                "name": "Dish 3"
            }
        ]
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Have you tried `getAllMenus().menus.indian`?

Comment: "indian" is the name of a property in your object. So as Colin says, you can simply reference that property. However if "indian" is the value inside a variable coming from some search field (e.g. if you had code such that `searchTerm = "indian"`, you might have to write ...`.menus[searchTerm]` so you can use the string variable to access the object property. Once you've got that, it's simple to loop through the items in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, properties and JSON keys are different. `getAllMenus().menus` will give you an error in this context. Instead, use `getAllMenus()['menus']` notation.

```
export interface Menu {
    indian: Item[];
    chinese: Item[];
    tabdoori: Item[];
}       

export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

function getMenu(response ,name){
   return response['menus'][name]
}
```

**Synchronous access**

If `getAllMenus` returns an object (and not an observable) :

```
const response: Menu = this.myApiService.getAllMenus();

console.log(getMenu(response, name));
```

**Asynchronous access**:

If `getAllMenus` returns an observable, and needs to be subscribed to :

```
this.myApiService.getAllMenus().pipe(
  map( response : Menu => getMenu(response, name))
)
.subscribe( nameItems=> console.log(nameItems) );
```

**Output** :

```
[
  {
    "id": "000123",
    "name": "Dish 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "000124",
    "name": "Dish 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "000125,
    "name": "Dish 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Menu%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20indian%3A%20Item%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chinese%3A%20Item%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tandoori%3A%20Item%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Item%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20menus%3A%20Menu%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22indian%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000123%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%201%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000124%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%202%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000125%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%203%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22chinese%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000126%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%204%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000127%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%205%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000128%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%206%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22tandoori%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000129%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%207%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000130%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%208%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22000131%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Dish%209%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%3A%20Item%5B%5D%20%3D%20menus.indian%3B) which shows the same but from local data. It does depend on what `getAllMenus` returns; I'm guessing it's asynchronous, so we'd need to know what it is that you're working with there.